# How to use more implementations of one interface in one class?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I would like to ask for your help regarding the following problem.

There is an interface which has more implementations:

```
public interface MyInterface {
    void method();
}
public class MyInterfaceA implements MyInterface
public class MyInterfaceB implements MyInterface
```

and there is a class which uses these implementations of the interface in its different methods:

```
public class MyClass {
    public void firstMethod() {
        new MyInterfaceA().method();
    }
    public void secondMethod() {
        new MyInterfaceB().method();
    }
}
```

My problem is that I wouldn't like to create new specific instances in the methods of the class, so somehow I would like to hide which implementation is used.

Do you know a nice solution for this? Is there any design pattern what I can use? How can I hide the concrete implementations or I cannot?

Thanks for your answers in advance!

Comment: The idea of an interface is that the calling class does not need to know the implementation. However, in the code you posted, it appears that the calling class needs to know the implementation. So what's the point of having an interface in the first place?

Comment: I see. I think I wanted to use interface wrong. I just wanted to separate functions in order to follow the Single Responsibility Principle. That's why I used an interface and created the implementations of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply the Factory pattern:

```
class Factory {
    public MyInterface a() { return new MyInterfaceA(); }
    public MyInterface b() { return new MyInterfaceB(); }
}

public class MyClass {
    private Factory factory;
    public MyClass(Factory factory) { this.factory = factory; }
    public void firstMethod() {
        factory.a().method();
    }
    public void secondMethod() {
        factory.b().method();
    }
}
```

Inside the `Factory` class you can cache the objects created if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

For example, you can receive the implementations in the constructor of `MyClass` and further use it. It helps you to hide the specific implementations.

```
public class MyClass {

    private MyInterface one;
    private MyInterface two;

    private MyClass(MyInterface one, MyInterface two) {
        this.one = one;
        this.two = two;
    }

    public void firstMethod() {
        one.method();
    }
    public void secondMethod() {
        two.method();
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the number of methods and the number of implementations of the interface can grow. So it means the constructor can become a lot of parameters constructor. I don't want to use a constructor with lots of parameters.
Btw thanks for your answer.

Comment: @josamiti You can then use a `List<MyInterface>` instead.

Comment: One of possible solution was suggested by  @MCEmperor. On the other hand, you can implement Builder pattern for construct complex object. And in the end, may be you should reorganize your architecture and decompose this class on the multiple classes?